# Passing extra properties to maven archetype:generate

Tags: maven-2, maven-archetype

I've created a Maven archetype for a custom project setup, which is working wonderfully, but I was wondering if it's possible to pass extra parameters so that I can do some more interesting templating. I tried something like

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -DdbHost=localhost
```

and put

```
...
<option name="db.host.config.option" value="${dbHost}" />
...
```

in my template, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this with an archetype?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just have to mention `dbHost` as `requiredProperty` in `META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml`.

```
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="dbHost"/>
    </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you expand on that a bit? I'm not sure I'm familiar enough with the syntax.

Comment: sure. In your archetype project, you have to create a folder project/META-INF/maven. In that folder you have to create a file called archetype-metadata.xml. In that file you should add requiredProperty tags for each of the configuration argument you would like to have. You can find more details here http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html

Comment: I've tried this, but ran into confusion between whether this should go in archetype-metadata.xml (as you suggest) or putting it in archetype.xml, and some of the content of archetype.xml not seeming to work if I put it in archetype-metadata.xml, and running into problems if I tried to have both files in my archetype together. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342578/whats-the-difference-between-archetype-xml-and-archetype-metadata-xml-in-maven

Answer (score 10):

Although this question is rather old, I'll provide my own experience with Maven 3.04

While *generating* the archetype from a project (**create-from-project**), you can pass a property file as an argument. Every single property **(key=value)** passed in will in turn generate a **requiredProperty** in the archetype-metadata.xml file, with "value" as its default value.
On the other hand, the archetype generation process will look for the string "value" in our text files and replace it by "${key}" **(i.e. dbHost=db.host.config.option would look for "db.host.config.option" and replace it by ${dbHost})**.

While *using* the archetype for the final project generation (with **generate**) we are offered the chance to provide a value for this parameter, with -D**key**=**value**. So there is no need to edit the archetype-metadata.xml file by hand.

Comment: Can you post an example on how passing a property file as argument to `mvn archetype:create-from-project`?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html#propertyFile

Comment: If you create a file with the default name (`archetype.properties`) in the root folder, no need to specify any property, it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: And what I just found: if you run the archetype generation in interactive mode (`-Dinteractive=true`) it will ask you if you want to provide additional properties and you can define them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

we need to pass property values in command prompt as well by maintaining it in archetype-metadat.xml but here name should not contain "." symbol as it does't allow you to update the values.

It is restriction in Maven to do not use name like prod.ex.version
you can use prod-ex-version