# What's the difference between archetype.xml and archetype-metadata.xml in Maven

Tags: maven

I'm trying to add additional variables to my archetype. Specifically, my archetype contains a logback.xml file, and I want to populate the log filename with the name of the project I'm generating from the archetype.

I was carrying out the instructions in the answer here [Passing extra properties to maven archetype:generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456676/passing-extra-properties-to-maven-archetypegenerate), but it says to add a `<requiredProperties>` element to my archetype-metadata.xml. My archetype doesn't have an archetype-metadata.xml, it only has an archetype.xml (which was generated automatically when I generated my archetype from maven-archetype-archetype).

In https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html, Maven refers to archetype.xml as an artifact-descriptor.

I googled archetype-metadata.xml, and found this - http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html. Maven calls it an archetype-descriptor as well, but its specification does not contain the id and resources elements that I see in my archetype.xml.

Are archetype.xml and archetype-metadata.xml the same thing? if not, what are their different purposes? Can I add a `<requiredProperties>` element to my archetype.xml file? Or should I create an archetype-metadata.xml file?

Comment: I suggest you start with `mvn archetype:create-from-project` which creates the template for the archetype.

Comment: I guess that the archetype.xml is following the schema described here: https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-registry/archetype-registry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the archetype descriptor (archetype-metadata.xml) as I suggested in the mentioned post,
[Passing extra properties to maven archetype:generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456676/passing-extra-properties-to-maven-archetypegenerate)

Here are the steps that I'm executing to generate the project:

```
    mkdir temp
    cd temp
    git clone git@github.com:jibbyj/appArchetype.git
    cd appArchetype
    mvn clean install
    mkdir run01
    cd run01
    ls
    mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.company.archetype \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=appArchetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.2-SNAPSHOT \
    -DarchetypeCatalog=local \
    -DinteractiveMode=false \
    -DgroupId=com.company \
    -DartifactId=test \
    -DappName=test
```

after this flow is completed, in test folder you can find the generated project.

In the `pom.xml`, the artifactId is set to the "test", also in `src/main/resources/logback.xml` the substitution is made.

Comment: When I do this, my archetype.xml file gets ignored, and my archetype resources do not get inserted into my project...

Comment: archetype.xml is not used. you should use archetype-metadata.xml. is there anyway that you can share the project?

Comment: @Jibbyj, please see my pull request on github (https://github.com/jibbyj/appArchetype/pull/1). It includes all the changes necessary to make it work. First of all, the packaging type should be maven-archetype and also you need to add the maven archetype as build extension. See pom.xml changes. Also the resources that need to be included should be defined also in archetype-metadata.xml.

Comment: I merged your changes and pulled down into my environment, but unfortunately, my archetype resources were still not copied into the generated project. I made sure to clean and deploy, I also removed previous version of the archetype from my local repository, and verified that the contents of the deployed jar file had your changes.

Comment: have you run "mvn clean install" on the archetype project before you have created the new project from the archetype?

Comment: Not at first, but then I did, and unfortunately no change.

Comment: quite impossible to understand what is your problem from the amount of information that you gave. I have updated the answer with the steps that I'm  executing in order to produce the expected output.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it worked. I must have mixed some configuration before. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The main takeaway from the accepted answer above was to use archetype-metadata.xml instead of archetype.xml, with a `<requiredProperties>` element, as well as a `<filesets>` element for the resources I want included. In archetype.xml it was a `<resources>` tag. Also give the archetype a `<packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>`.

Still not totally clear though what the difference is between archetype.xml and archetype-metadata.xml. Assume archetype.xml is deprecated?

Comment: As far as I look to the referenced document it is looking just as being a typing error in the documentation.  If you check the link, then you can see that is pointing to archetype-metadata.xml description.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I followed the instructions at the bottom of https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html, using -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-archetype to generate an archetype template, and it created archetype.xml, not archetype-metadata.xml

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no answer for the question what the difference is between archetype.xml and archetype-metadata.xml:

As specified in the documentation https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/archetype.html *archetype.xml* was used for schema version 1.0.0. *archetype-metadata.xml* is used with schema version 1.1.0.

**archetype.xml:**

*Maven's model for the old archetype descriptor (ie for Archetype 1.0.x).
The metadata about an archetype is stored in the archetype.xml file located in the META-INF/maven directory of its jar file.*

**archetype-metadata.xml:**

*This is a reference for the Archetype descriptor used to describe archetypes's metadata.
The metadata about an archetype is stored in the archetype-metadata.xml file located in the META-INF/maven directory of its jar file.*