# Using custom properties in your own maven archetype

Tags: java, maven

**UPDATED** (after reading [Passing extra properties to maven archetype:generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456676/passing-extra-properties-to-maven-archetypegenerate)):

I created my own archetype. The src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>$groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>$artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>$version</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>$groupId</groupId>
                <artifactId>${3rdPartyDepsArtifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${3rdPartyDepsVersion}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Want to use my own 3rd-party-deps-artifact and 3rd-party-deps-version parameters. So I added the src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml file:

```
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="3rdPartyDepsArtifactId"/>
        <requiredProperty key="3rdPartyDepsVersion"/>
    </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

Install archetype into my local repository. And then create artifact based on my custom archetype:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=test
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=test2 -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -D3rdPartyDepsArtifactId=3rd-party-deps -D3rdPartyDepsVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=test3 -DartifactId=my_test -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

In the output I can see that both 3rdPartyDepsVersion and 3rdPartyDepsArtifactId are applied now:
Confirm properties configuration:

```
groupId: ...
artifactId: ...
version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
package: ...
3rdPartyDepsArtifactId: 3rd-party-deps
3rdPartyDepsVersion: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

But in the generated project, inside of dependencyManagement these properties are still ignored:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test3</groupId>
            <artifactId>${3rdPartyDepsArtifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${3rdPartyDepsVersion}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

How can I force maven to use 3rdPartyDepsArtifactId and 3rdPartyDepsVersion properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing extra properties to maven archetype:generate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456676/passing-extra-properties-to-maven-archetypegenerate)

Comment: @AleksandrM, I tried to use the solution, but without success

Comment: Try with some simple name instead of `3rdPartyDepsArtifactId`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is possible as you want it but an alternative approach could be to include the property in your `settings.xml` (within a profile) or pass them within the maven command `-D`.